# Jittering when trying to move undercorated JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have made a custome `JFrame` called `mainWindow` that is undecorated. I have added a `JLabel` named `dragBar` at the top of it and gave it desired dimensions (as shown below). When I click on the label I make the window move according to my mouse by using two listeners; one `MouseListener` and one `MouseMotionListener`.
The problem is that whenever I click on the label the window does move according to my mouse's location but it spazzes all over my screen until I stop moving the mouse or let go of the click button.
Is my method wrong? What is causing this issue?
Here is my code:

```
    //what i use to make the dragBar
    private JLabel dragBar = new JLabel();
    private Point initialClick; //the initial point where I click on the label
    //my mainWindow JFrame
    private JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
    private Dimension mainWindowSize = new Dimension(680,410);

    //the code I use to set up my mainWindow JFrame
    mainWindow.setUndecorated(true);
    mainWindow.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 670, 400, 5, 5));
    mainWindow.setSize(mainWindowSize);
    mainWindow.setMinimumSize(mainWindowSize);
    mainWindow.setResizable(false);
    mainWindow.setLocation((screen_size.width/2)- mainWindow.getWidth()/2, (screen_size.height/2)- mainWindow.getHeight()/2);
    mainWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(46, 48, 50, 255));

    //the code I use to set up my dragBar label
    topContainer.add(dragBar,3); //a Jlayeredpane that contains the dragBar label and is added to the mainWindow
    dragBar.setSize(topContainer.getSize());
    dragBar.setLocation(0,0);
    dragBar.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            initialClick = e.getPoint();
        }
        @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
        @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
    dragBar.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int changeX = e.getX()-initialClick.x;
            int changeY = e.getY()-initialClick.y;

            mainWindow.setLocation(mainWindow.getX()+changeX, mainWindow.getY()+changeY);
        }
        @Override public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> a Jlayeredpane that contains the dragBar label

Don't think I would use a JLayeredPane for this. Just add a component to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` of the frame.

The basic logic for dragging a component is something like:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

However in your case you don't want to drag the label, but instead drag the window, you your logic needs to forward the events to the window.

Check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a more complex implementation of the above code that also adds additional features that easily allow you to move a window.

Comment: Even though your code works fine and the "forward the events to the window" comment does help a lot, the question is about me *understanding* why the window jitters and if this code fixes that, then why is that so.

Comment: @Lae, We are not here to debug your code. Did you look at how I calculate the x/y values and compare it to your code? The problem is that the events and the x/y values in the MouseEvent is not what you expect. Did you do any debugging? Did you display the value of the variables that you calculate?